# "Leave open the possibility of a stretch-mark fetishist"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain to me the meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "stretch mark" is simply the wrinkles a woman has, on her belly, after being pregnant and having a baby. (You know, the flabby skin that can be there, after having a baby.)

A "fetish" is an unusual sexual desire.  So, a "foot fetish" is being sexually attracted to feet. An "ear fetish" is finding ears really sexy.

Now, it is normal, for comic effect, to talk of a ridiculous fetish.  For example, "I have a road sign fetish" (for some bizarre reason, road signs turn me on) or "She has a potato fetish" (potatoes arouse her sexually).

If you understand the phrase "Leave open the possibility..." you now understand the sarcasm or comedy that is being made here.

(It's likely a woman writer, sarcastically saying something like: "Well, I sure will not be attractive after I have the baby! Of course, there's the possibility of a stretch-mark fetishist!")

Comment: Its really cool. Now, I am really enjoying learning english. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi @poorenglish!  You'll be enjoying *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* any day now!  Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for that too..seems to be a good movie..i will start it immediately after I wind up this one..

Comment: The *Hitchhiker's Guide* is PACKED with local, difficult language - you will enjoy it! A comic classic.  (I would forget about the movie, it's hopeless.)  Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

More context would have been nice. It turns out this is from *Youth in Revolt* and the earlier statements in the conversation are:

> "Nick, how many men are interested in a woman who's 48 years old...
>
> ...has a kid, no money and stretch marks?"
>
> "I think you're selling yourself short, Mom."

Stretch marks occur on a woman's stomach when she's pregnant. The skin has to stretch to accommodate the baby. After birth, even though the skin goes back to its previous size (more or less), there are still marks. Nick is stating that maybe she'll find a man who find stretch marks sexually exciting. A fetishist is someone who focuses on a particular item (like women's shoes) or body part.